# vpn and proxy to get ip from another network

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy

i used to be connected to a server in the US and i got it's IP so i could get to pandora from outside of the US.

now i need to be connected to another computer of mine, windows xp home, and my workstation is windows 7.

i want to be able to get it's ip so i can have access to something that only it's ip will have

how can i do it? i tried the logmein vpn, didn't work, the windows built it didn't work...

is it possible to do it with proxy+? or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

First... Don't do stuff that's illegal.  It makes the rest of us legal people have to pay for your stupidity.

Second, assuming your workstations are all in the same local network, you shouldn't have to make any changes to any settings.  Local routes take precedence over default routes every day of the week.  Which VPN client/technology you use doesn't change this.  If they're in separate networks, you might want to simply add a static on your local machine to the network of the other workstations.

Comment: Some VPNs will globally route all data through the VPN, depending upon configuration. It is impossible to access local computers other than the internet gateway when the VPN is configured like this, unless you manually add routes to the system. Just wanting to point out that it's possible to have a VPN mess with local routing.

Comment: First i didn't do anything illegal, it was my US computer and when i was traveling i wanted music with me so i used the vpn. now what i need is for my home computer to be connected to another location that i have (both on separate isp connections) and i need to have access to it's IP. i didn't understand what you said about the static that need to be add. the windows 7 to xp home vpn connection is not working for me at all

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're not one of the many folk out there who spoil the free good stuff for the rest of us...  sorry if I came off as a bit flippant.

On the VPN subject... Proxy+ is merely a socks proxy and probably won't do the job for your needs.  Any private networks you want to have access to... you'll need an entry point of some sort.  Simply allowing access to your machine is very insecure... and will probably result in a very bad outcome.  You'll need to setup a VPN gateway at each "private-network" you want access to... and on your roaming machine, simply connect to each network.

Comment: is there a testing tool out there? i allow the vpn connection of the windows xp home and try to connect to it with the windows 7- it is not working. how can i test ports and firewall?

Comment: Most VPN flavors require more than just a port or 2 to be open.  PPTP (for example) requires a specific protocol to be allowed to traverse (GRE) not just a port.  IPSEC requires ESP and AH protocols.  Those are the 2 big ones natively supported by Microsoft products.  Alternatives that will work through port-forwarding are usually expensive to implement (SSL-based VPN) or very difficult to setup (OpenVPN) unless you know what you're doing.  Sadly, this is exactly why everyone isn't doing it.